# Javascript function not changing color, also need a regex to recognize more characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, function

I have this function to reconize and add a color to #hashtags in javascript

html

```
<input id="input"  onkeyup="changecolor()" type="text"></input>
```

js function

```
<script>
     function changecolor() {
        return html.replace(/(\#\w+)/g, '<span style="color: blue">$1</span>');   
     }); 
 </script>
```

somehow it do not works when using input.

I also would like a regex to make it reconize `@` and `http:// - https://` inside the input

Comment: You cannont place HTML inside input fields

Comment: what is the alternative so?

Comment: Maybe copy the value of the input field to a div (underneath) and display the text with HTML there. But it depends what you acutally want to achieve with this

Comment: cool, and about the regex part to `@` and `http:// - https://` what expression would you use?

Comment: I've added an example as an answer. With an extended regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex

[**`/((\#|\@|(https?:\/\/))[^ ]{1,})/g`**](https://regex101.com/r/CGP5w4/2)

```js
function changecolor(input) {
  document.getElementById('tag').innerHTML = 
    input.value.replace(/((\#|\@|(https?:\/\/))[^ ]{1,})/g, '<span style="color: blue">$1</span>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" onkeyup="changecolor(this)" type="text">
<div id="tag"></div>
```

Comment: By looking your code i think its what i want, i AM on phone now, i Will try soon.

Comment: could you keep this solution and also add another solution to input only return the `@`value ?

Comment: Just change the # to @ in your sample code. Thats it

Comment: I want to use it in another function  `$("#text_output").text(currentText)` how would I make `(currentText)` converted to regex?

Comment: this is the function I want to convert `<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img_description").keyup(function(){
        // Getting the current value of textarea
        var currentText = $(this).val();
         // Setting the Div content
        $("#text_output").text(currentText)
        //$("#text_output").text(currentText);
        //$("#text_output").value(currentText);
         $("#text_output").attr("value", currentText);
    });
});

</script>`

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following regex to determine if it is a URL.

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

Comment: Cool, I Will implement in the function